# Does the testandtarget.js file have a purpose?

Tags: aem

While analyzing some requests on our dispatcher, we noticed that we continually get a 0 byte file generated from hitting the following path

```
/etc/clientlibs/foundation/testandtarget
```

This file is a ClientLibraryFolder.  Its js.txt defines the base file as such:

```
#base=source
```

There is no "source" folder that is a direct child of testandtarget.  The testandtarget folder contains two ClientLibraryFolders, mbox and util.  The js in these folders is loaded on the page just fine.  This is why Test&Target still works.  However, the testandtarget ClientLib seems to be wrong by default (this is the OOB 5.5 setup).  We get a 0 byte file because the js.txt file's base points to a folder that does not exist.

Is anyone else seeing the behavior?  It appears that I could just rewrite the js.txt file.  Are there any ramifications for doing so?

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell, that node is an empty clientlib, but it has a child node of "mbox" with the same clientlibrary category.  That clientlibrary WILL produce content, and references a `source` folder beneath it.

- http://{localhost}/libs/cq/ui/content/dumplibs.test.html?categories=testandtarget
- http://{localhost}/libs/cq/ui/content/dumplibs.html?categories=testandtarget&type=JS&theme=

I am not aware of the version history, and whether it used to have valid content, or is planned to in the future.

I would be more tempted to remove or change the category than to play with the js.txt file.  Editing the js.txt file will change what content goes into the clientlib.  Changing/removing the category would no longer cause a call out to the zero byte file.

```
<cq:includeClientLib categories="testandtarget" />
```

=>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/clientlibs/foundation/testandtarget/mbox.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/clientlibs/foundation/testandtarget.js">